# Sorting an array by external values in a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have this code:

```
var myarray = [ "cars", "planes", "houses", "food"]

for(let x of myarray) {
     var name = things.map(d => d.id == x ? d.name : []).join('');
     var price = things.map(d => d.id == x ? d.things : []).join('');
     
     document.getElementById('list').innerHTML += `
      <div>${name} : ${price}</div>`;
    }
```

This will output this:

```
<div>cars : 2000</div>
<div>planes : 199000</div>
<div>houses: 67000</div>
<div>food: 100</div>
```

but I want this sorted by PRICE so the output should be like this instead:

```
<div>planes : 199000</div>
<div>houses: 67000</div>
<div>cars : 2000</div>
<div>food: 100</div>
```

I know sort() pretty much does the job but the problem here is that `price` is being pulled out from another array so I don't know how to put everything together.

Comment: do you have `things` as well?

Comment: yes, sorry I didnt post it but its a big array.

Comment: please post a small amount to get the structure and what problem the data may give.

Comment: The answer has been posted. Thank you.

Comment: If it is a big array then you have accepted an inefficient answer both for its nested `find()` call and its incremental updating of the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array#map` to create a new array where every element is replaced with the corresponding object from the other array, then sort based on the `things` field.

```js
let myarray = [ "cars", "planes", "houses", "food"];
myarray.map(x => things.find(d => d.id == x))
    .sort((a, b) => b.things - a.things)
    .forEach(o => {
        document.getElementById('list').append(Object.assign(document.createElement('div'), {textContent: `${o.name} : ${o.things}`}));
    });
```

Comment: See a working demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/2sL3vadb/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of mapping over `myarray`, use it to [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) your `things` array, then [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) by price.

Here using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) created from your array of `id`s as the filter target.

```js
const myarray = ['cars', 'planes', 'food'];

const things = [
  { id: 'cars', name: 'Car', price: 2000 },
  { id: 'planes', name: 'Plane', price: 199000 },
  { id: 'houses', name: 'House', price: 67000 },
  { id: 'food', name: 'Food', price: 100 },
];

const myarraySet = new Set(myarray);
const result = things
  .filter(({ id }) => myarraySet.has(id))
  .sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price);

console.log(result);
```

Also it is better to build the complete list first and then add it to the DOM once rather than repeatedly setting the `innerHTML`. Here is an example using a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment)

```js
const myarray = ['cars', 'planes', 'food'];
const things = [{ id: 'cars', name: 'Car', price: 2000 }, { id: 'planes', name: 'Plane', price: 199000 }, { id: 'houses', name: 'House', price: 67000 }, { id: 'food', name: 'Food', price: 100 },];

const myarraySet = new Set(myarray);
const result = things
  .filter(({ id }) => myarraySet.has(id))
  .sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price);

// Build the list in a DocumentFragment and then append
const list = document.getElementById("list");
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (const thing of result){
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = `${thing.name}: ${thing.price}`;
  fragment.appendChild(li);
}

list.appendChild(fragment);
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```